# Magento : Gender Select box empty

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-account

In the create account form the *Gender* Select box options are empty

[image]

Comment: please check Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getAllOptions() give array of gender list

Comment: Do you using any other language(not english) for your shop? maybe in this language pack gender names replaced with empty value

Comment: thank you Amit Bera, 
but how can I find Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSour‌​ce()->getAllOptions() ?

Comment: sIiiS, i don't use any other language . thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**resolved**

First you need to identify the gender attribute from Database with running the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'gender'
```

take the id of the resulted row. For me it's 18.

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option` SET `attribute_id` = 18, `sort_order` = 0;
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option` SET `attribute_id` = 18, `sort_order` = 1;
```

This will insert 2 options. for the attribute (replace 18 with the id you get from the first select).

Now these 2 inserted rows should have an autoincrement value for option_id. 
[image]
Take these 2 values and run the following queries. Let's say the value are 9 and 10.

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option_value` set `option_id` = 9, `store_id` = 0, `value` = 'Male';
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option_value` set `option_id` = 10, `store_id` = 0, `value` = 'Female';
```

This will insert the option labels. Replace 9 and 10 with the values you get after the first set of inserts.

Clear the cache should be set.

Comment: I wonder why did you lose these values from database? Sure magento CE has no native solutions for editing customer attributes. So probably it happened when you with something similar lose these values.

Comment: So me, I'm marveled
I don't log to my sql Database since one year ,but error appear from 2 days
and after resolving this issue I have another: when I try to purchase an Item 'When I Click on Place Order" I get this error message on console:
.prototype.js:828 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined

and Order was not placed.

Comment: I must be your database issue

Answer (score 1):

First,you need to check `Mage::getResourceModel'customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSour‌​ce()->getAllOptions()`  give the list of gender list.If it is `not given the data` then the `attribute does not have any option` then you need to `update the attribute with new options`

Comment: Thnks, 
but where can I find: Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSour‌​ce()->getAllOptions() ?